# Profile based Spring Cloud Config Server client with optional local developer properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, properties-file, spring-cloud-config

### My Goal:

Having the Spring Cloud Config Server import active and provide a way for developers to have an optional property file on their machine.

[image: wanted cfg prio diagram]

My Config Server is up and running using `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server:3.1.3` and `@EnableConfigServer` on the main class. Http requests to the concrete endpoint yield the expected result. This server should provide important environment configurations for a developer for his/her local setup.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8888/test-application/dev
```

```json
{"name":"test-application","profiles":["dev"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"classpath:/cfg/test-application/application-dev.yml","source":{"server.port":1111}},{"name":"classpath:/cfg/test-application/application.yml","source":{"server.port":8000}}]}
```

Where `localhost:8888` is my Config Server and `test-application` ist the name of the client application (defined via `spring.application.name`). The provided `dev` is the currently active profile on the client (The dev profile indicates a locally running software, there is no dev environment).

### Clients configuration:

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test-application
  config:
    import:
      - configserver:http://localhost:8888                  # <- pull the configuration from the configserver
      - optional:file:/absolute/path/to/the/project/root/   # <- if there are any additional configuration files, use them
```

The client uses the following dependencies:

- `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.0`
- `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:3.1.3`
- `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:3.1.3`
- `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:3.1.3`

As shown above, the "base" `application.yml` configured `server.port=8000` where the profile specific is set to `server.port=1111`. When reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-files-importing) this behaviour is correct. But my local developer configuration contains `server.port=2222`. This was ignored.

### Here comes the problem:

When starting the client application, i can see the following log statements:

```
Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
Located environment: name=test-application, profiles=[default], label=null, version=null, state=null
Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-classpath:/cfg/test-application/application-dev.yml'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-classpath:/cfg/test-application/application.yml'}]
The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
Tomcat initialized with port(s): 1111 (http)
Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Tomcat started on port(s): 1111 (http) with context path ''
Started TestApplicationKt in 2.234 seconds (JVM running for 2.762)
```

The configuration evaluation result from spring was to choose port `1111` instead of the wanted `2222` within the `application-dev.yml` located in the project root (developer config).

---

### Wrapped up:

Three config files:

1. config server `application.yml` (port: 8000)
2. config server `application-dev.yml` (port: 1111)
3. project root developer config `application-dev.yml` (port: 2222) <- I want this file to have precedence over the other two.

When running the debugger, i see these found property sources within the injected `Environment` bean. The wanted developer file is within this list and the property source content is correct (`server.port=2222`).

[image: Environment runtime snapshot]

**Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?**

I have created a project that reproduces this exact behaviour. [Link to GitHub](https://github.com/wartoshika/stackoverflow-q72736083).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `dev` profile active when application is running in dev environment or it's also active when running locally?
Ideally you should have 2 different profiles for dev and local and you can enable config server only when `dev` profile is active.
You can rename your local property file as `application-local.yml` and disable spring cloud config when profile `local` is active.
You can put below code in `bootstrap.yml`(create new file beside `application.yml`) and remove config server configurations from `application.yml`

```
---
spring:
  application:
    name: test-application
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
    import:
      - configserver:http://localhost:8888                  # <- pull the configuration from the configserver
      - optional:file:/absolute/path/to/the/project/root/   # <- if there are any additional configuration files, use them
---
spring:
  application:
    name: test-application
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
```

**EDIT: Actual fix**

Thanks for sharing reproducible example.
All you need to do is remove local `application-dev.yml` location reference from client `application.yml` and add it to configServer `application.yml` as shown in belolow screenshots.

*/**client**/src/main/resources/application.yml*
[image]

And put it in configServer `application.yml` **at the end of search-locations**. Order matters so please make sure you put overriding location/s at the end.

*/**configServer**/src/main/resources/application.yml*
[image]

Build and start both the applications and you will see client application server started on port 2222
[image]

Comment: The `dev` profile is only active when running locally, we do not have a dev environment.

When using this configuration, the local developer config must contain every other property that should be read from the configserver.

Comment: Is there a way to support config server AND a local property file without the need of duplicated properties?

Comment: My alternative idea is to let every developer have an `application-dev.yml` within the local copy of the config server to achive this result. But i would like to prefer a project local solution

Comment: If you do not have dev environment then why do you need config server? You can simply put `application-dev.yml` in `src/main/resources` folder of project and remove config server configuration. If you really need config server but want each developer to run local server on different port, developers can also provide different port while application startup.

You can below command if you are using maven
`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8000`

Or you can also set it in IDEs you use. 
You said you can share test application. If you can do that, it would be nice

Comment: I will upload this project today evening ~07pm MEZ. I will also draw an additional picture that may clarifies some of my ideas. Thanks!

Comment: The project is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/wartoshika/stackoverflow-q72736083). I have edited my question and displayed it there as well.

Comment: Added an additional diagram that may tell more :) Thank you

Comment: Thanks for sharing reproducible example. Now I understood your problem and what you are trying to achieve. I was able to reproduce issue locally and fix it. 
All you had to do is remove local `application-dev.yml` location from client `application.yml` and add it to congigServer `application.yml`. I will update answer with screenshots.
I was not able to push fix to your git repo(getting 403), so I pushed it to my repo. You can check the fix/changes [here](https://github.com/spote87/stackoverflow-q72736083)

Comment: Thanks for your time, this is indeed a good working solution!